# How to allow special tags in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a `textarea` for commenting. I need to allow tags such as `'` and `\` as well as `html` tags (e.g `<b> , <i> , <br>`).

I tried `htmlspecialchars($comment,ENT_QUOTES);` , but this way `'` and `\` are allowed but `html` tags aren't. That is the input `assassin's <b>creed` becomes exactly `assassin's <b>creed`. But i need it to become assassin's **creed**.

Whereas if i don't use `htmlspecialchars($comment,ENT_QUOTES);` , `assassin's <b>creed` makes trouble... because of the `'` . But `assassins <b>creed` becomes assassin's **creed** as it should.

How could i solve this problem?

I hope it's clear enough

Thanks

**edit:**

This is how it should be:

input: `assassin's <b>creed`

output: assassin's **creed**

by using `htmlspecialchars`:

input: `assassin's <b>creed`

output: `assassin's <b>creed`

without using any functions:

input: `assassin's <b>creed`

can't insert to database

without using any functions:

input: `assassins <b>creed`

output: assassins **creed**

Comment: Why is the apostrophe causing trouble?

Comment: @PhilCross it fails to insert it to the database. In the SQL database the comment field type is TEXT. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: @Dwza `htmlentities()` doesn't seem to do anything... <b> does make bold , but `'` still makes trouble.

Comment: dont use ', use ´ instead the ' may is like injecting sql

Comment: Are you escaping your data?!!?! If you escape your data properly before inserting into the database, you shouldn't have this issue. It would seem your SQL injecting yourself! How are you saving the data to the database?

Comment: and you could try addslashes($comment)

Comment: @PhilCross that's what i'm trying to do... escape the data. but i'm saying that `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` aren't helping to escape it

Comment: by "becomes exactly assasssin's <b>creed" do you mean that's the exact text you see in the textarea and you want it to look bold *inside* the textarea? Or am I misunderstanding it ?

Comment: @AlaaM. htmlentities and htmlspecialcharacters are not meant for escaping to put into a database. What you are looking for is prepared statements.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `htmlspecialchars()` to escape your data ;) What functions are you using to insert the data? `mysql_query()`, `PDO`, `MySQLi`?

Comment: @PhilCross `mysql_query()`

Comment: please see edit above... i clarified it

Comment: @Mike prepared statements?

Comment: @AlaaM. See http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements or http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. You should not be using the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `htmlspecialchars()` to escape database data.

This shouldn't be used to escape data destined for a database. It would seem that you are inadvertantly SQL injecting yourself.

As I don't know how your connecting to your database, I'll post a couple of ways to escape your data properly:

**mysql**
Although you shouldn't be using this functionality, as its deprecated and not supported, I'll post how to escape properly:

```
$data = "Assassin's <b>creed</b>";

$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO .... ");
```

**PDO**

```
$conn = new PDO("{$connection_string}");

$data = "Assassin's <b>Creed</b>";
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_games (title) VALUES (?)");
$conn->execute(array($data));
```

**CodeIgniter**

```
$this->db->insert('tbl_games', array('title' => "Assassin's <b>Creed</b>"));
```

I'm not sure of mysqli functionality (or others).
In any case, you shouldn't need to use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape your data.

Either use the database's built in functionality for escaping the data, or research prepared statements.

- [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)
- [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
- [MySQL_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
- [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)
- [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

Comment: I'm using **mysql**. And `mysql_real_escape_string()` didn't help. Still can't insert to the database.

Comment: You should be getting an error. Whats the error message?

Comment: escaping for sql (like your recommendations) is not enough to stop xss vulnerabilities. still it may get inside some malicious data....

Comment: @optional I know, `strip_tags()` should be used, with tag exceptions, however the answer is how to escape data, and therefore get the database queries working correctly rather than XSS vuns.

Comment: @PhilCross the problem with `strip_tags()` is that it doesn't strip attributes from the allowed tags, so a malicious person could still add an `onmouseover` to one of the allowed tags and it won't be filtered.

Comment: @PhilCross Cross I see great benefits to point that there are other vulnerabilities while using this kind of escaping. at the bottom of the line, op escape data for security. biggest purpose here is security. your answer ok but missing this important note...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to allow html tags etc you can not sanitize data with htmlspecialchars or similar php functions. You have to use libraries for this purpose (sanitizing data while allowing tags inoffensively) I recommend [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Or you may use WYSIWYG web editors like http://www.tinymce.com/ or http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: If you look at the comments from the question, the OP is wondering about inserting the text into a database, not displaying it back on the page.

Comment: @Mike why he/she insert to database. especially, if he want to accept html tags... this data will display... :) we are not robots, we are humans and we must think about all posibilities...

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use a library such as [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) (mentioned in optional's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805310/650329)). If this isn't an option, a function like the following will allow you to preserve html tags:

```
function htmlspecialchars_whitelist(
        array $whitelist,
        $string,
        $flags = ENT_COMPAT,
        $encoding = 'UTF-8',
        $double_encode = true) {

    $regex = implode('|', $whitelist);
    preg_match_all("#<(?:(?:$regex) ?/?|/(?:$regex))>#", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    $pos = 0;
    $buffer = '';

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $off = $match[0][3];
        $substr = substr($string, $pos, $off - $pos);
        $substr = htmlspecialchars($substr, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);
        $buffer .= $substr;
        $buffer .= $match[0][0];
        $pos = $off + strlen($match[0][0]);
    }

    $buffer .= htmlspecialchars(substr($string, $pos), $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);

    return $buffer;
}
```

Example:

```
$whitelist = array('b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'strike', 'br');
$html = "<p>The <strike>quick</strike> \"brown\" <strong>fox</strong> jumped <hr /> 'over' the <em>lazy dog</em>.</p>";
echo htmlspecialchars_whitelist($whitelist, $html, ENT_QUOTES);
// &lt;p&gt;The <strike>quick</strike> &quot;brown&quot; <strong>fox</strong> jumped &lt;hr /&gt; &#039;over&#039; the <em>lazy dog</em>.&lt;/p&gt;
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yru-fb1

Note: you must still guard against SQL injection. Phil Cross' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805244/650329) tackles this.